# Partition data within an Azure SQL Data Warehouse table

Tags: sql-server, azure-synapse

I'm trying to get a little hands on with partitioned tables within Azure SQL Data Warehouse.  But I'm seeing things that don't make sense to me.  I'm obviously doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what it is.

My intention is to populate the first table (Marc.foo) with 10000 rows of data, examine the partitioning metadata, then SWITCH a partition to the second, empty table (Marc.foo2).

I start off by creating two partitioned tables:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Marc.foo', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE Marc.foo
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('Marc.foo2', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE Marc.foo2
GO

CREATE TABLE Marc.foo
(
    id int NOT NULL
)
WITH 
(   
     DISTRIBUTION = HASH (id),
     CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX, 
     PARTITION (id RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES (0, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000))
)
GO

CREATE TABLE Marc.foo2
(
    id int NOT NULL
)
WITH 
(   
     DISTRIBUTION = HASH (id),
     CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX, 
     PARTITION (id RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES (0, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000))
)
GO
```

I then populate the first table (Marc.foo) with 10000 rows:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#numbers', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #numbers
GO

WITH 
    CTE_2 AS (SELECT 1 as id UNION ALL SELECT 1 as id), 
    CTE_4 AS (SELECT a.id FROM CTE_2 a, CTE_2 b), 
    CTE_16 AS (SELECT a.id FROM CTE_4 a, CTE_4 b), 
    CTE_256 AS (SELECT a.id FROM CTE_16 a, CTE_16 b), 
    CTE_64K AS (SELECT a.id FROM CTE_256 a, CTE_256 b)
SELECT      id
INTO        #numbers
FROM        CTE_64K

INSERT INTO Marc.foo(id)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM #numbers WHERE id <=10000
```

Because I just loaded data into the table, I'm going to create statistics on the table:

```
CREATE STATISTICS stats_Marc_foo_id ON Marc.foo(id) WITH FULLSCAN
```

Now I examine the partitioning metadata:

```
SELECT      sch.name AS [schema_name],
            tbl.[name] AS [table_name],
            ds.type_desc, 
            prt.[partition_number],
            rng.[value] AS [current_partition_range_boundary_value],
            prt.[rows] AS [partition_rows]
FROM        sys.schemas                             sch
            INNER JOIN sys.tables                   tbl ON  sch.schema_id       = tbl.schema_id
            INNER JOIN sys.partitions               prt ON  prt.[object_id]     = tbl.[object_id]
            INNER JOIN sys.indexes                  idx ON  prt.[object_id]     = idx.[object_id] AND prt.[index_id] = idx.[index_id]
            INNER JOIN sys.data_spaces              ds  ON  idx.[data_space_id] = ds.[data_space_id]
            INNER JOIN sys.partition_schemes        ps  ON  ds.[data_space_id]  = ps.[data_space_id]
            INNER JOIN sys.partition_functions      pf  ON  ps.[function_id]    = pf.[function_id]
            LEFT JOIN sys.partition_range_values    rng ON  pf.[function_id]    = rng.[function_id] AND rng.[boundary_id] = prt.[partition_number]
WHERE       sch.name = 'Marc' AND
            tbl.name = 'foo'
```

**Question 1:** This gives me what I expect in terms of current_partition_range_boundary_value, but partition_rows (which I expect to be 1000) is returning 5957 rows for each partition.

Last, I try to SWITCH Partition 1 from Marc.foo to Marc.foo2

```
ALTER TABLE Marc.foo SWITCH PARTITION 1 to Marc.foo2 PARTITION 1
```

I expect that when I SELECT from Marc.foo2, I should see 1000 rows with id values from 1 to 1000.  But I get back zero rows.

**Question 2:**  What I have I done wrong?

Answer (score 3):

There is an error in your code.  Your CTE brings back the number 1 for all rows, which you can confirm by checking the contents of the `#numbers` table.  So your criteria for `id <= 10000` has no effect and the statement always brings back 65,536 rows:

[image: 1 1 1 1 1]

Correct this by moving your `ROW_NUMBER` up into the `SELECT ... INTO`, eg

```
WITH 
    CTE_2 AS (SELECT 1 as id UNION ALL SELECT 1 as id), 
    CTE_4 AS (SELECT a.id FROM CTE_2 a, CTE_2 b), 
    CTE_16 AS (SELECT a.id FROM CTE_4 a, CTE_4 b), 
    CTE_256 AS (SELECT a.id FROM CTE_16 a, CTE_16 b), 
    CTE_64K AS (SELECT a.id FROM CTE_256 a, CTE_256 b)
SELECT      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))  AS id
INTO        #numbers
FROM        CTE_64K
```

I guess the moral of the story is, do not write your own number generation routine without checking it : )

Answer (score 3):

Numbers tables aside, here was the issue

> Question 1: This gives me what I expect in terms of current_partition_range_boundary_value, but partition_rows (which I expect to be 1000) is returning 5957 rows for each partition.

I still can't get answers I expect from this.

Last, I try to SWITCH Partition 1 from `Marc.foo` to `Marc.foo2`.

```
ALTER TABLE Marc.foo SWITCH PARTITION 1 to Marc.foo2 PARTITION 1
```

I expect that when I SELECT from Marc.foo2, I should see 1000 rows with id values from 1 to 1000. But I get back zero rows.

> Question 2: What I have I done wrong?

I misinterpreted RANGE RIGHT. If we look at the partition clause of the CREATE TABLE we see:

```
PARTITION (id RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES (0, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 
6000, 7000, 8000, 9000)))
```

This means that rows with an ID up to but not including zero will be in partition 1, rows with an ID between 0 and 999 will be in partition 2.

There were no rows in partition 1.  This was working as designed.  If I switched partition 2, rows appear in `Marc.foo2`.